# Uniquess of solutions to the following partial differential equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I solved these two partial differential equations by the characteristics method and I got the following solutions:

For $(\partial_t + {x}t^2\, \partial_x) u = 0  \text{ in} \Omega$,  $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $u(0,x)=f(x)$ I got $u(t,x)=f\left(xe^{-t}\right)$

For $(\partial_t + {x^3}\, \partial_x) u = 0 \text{ in }\Omega,
    u(0,x)=f(x), x\in\mathbb{R}$ I got $u(t,x)=f\left(\cfrac{x}{xt+1}\right)$

the solutions I obtained are unique in $\mathbb{R}^2$

I really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two PDEs are transformed into one same PDE by convenient change of variable.

$$\text{With}\quad x=e^X\qquad (\partial_t + {x}\, \partial_x) u = 0\quad\implies\quad (\partial_t +  \partial_X) u = 0\tag 1$$

$$\text{With}\quad x=-\frac{1}{X}\qquad (\partial_t + {x^2}\, \partial_x) u = 0\quad\implies\quad (\partial_t +  \partial_X) u = 0\tag 2$$

In both cases the general solution is
$$\boxed{u=F(X-t)}$$

Case $(1): \qquad u=F(\ln|x|-t)=f(xe^t)\quad $ with $\quad f(z)=F(e^z)$

Case $(2) : \qquad u=F(-\frac{1}{x}-t)=f(\frac{x}{xt+1})\quad$ with $\quad f(z)=-\frac{1}{F(z)}$